# How do I Wake on LAN and Wake on WAN using Port Triggering instead of Port Forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

So I have an old windows 7 machine from 2013 I believe the motherboard is also a MSI MPower Z77 for those who want specs. My modem is an xfinity xfi modem. I use my galaxy s9+ with Verizon service to wake up the PC. (My cell service is not comcast/xfinity). I use the app, WolOn. By the way Remote Management is turned off in the modem's administrator dashboard/UI.

I've gotten 100% successful Wake on LAN for this PC when I'm connected to my home network and partial success for Wake on WAN when I am like in another state using mobile data. But let's say I'm at my house. I have WiFi turned off on my phone and switch to connect to mobile data I get a 100% success rate to wake the pc.

Now I usually have everything set up with Port Forwarding, however port forwarding is very insecure as the specified ports are always open. I heard that with Port Triggering, when the port isn't used frequently the port is closed, but since it will save IP addresses of a device automatically when the ports are active and being used by a device. Also you can set a rule for a single port to be used by multiple devices unlike port forwarding where lets say port 2 will always be tied to a single IP address (device).

I've set up a rule for Port Triggering, removed all my port forwarding rules and I haven't gotten Wake on WAN to work at all while I'm at home using the method I described above to get a 100% success rate for Wake on WAN.

Also Wake on LAN still works but I'm not even sure why it's working because I did a test after disabling port triggering. So ports 7 and ports 9 are not being triggered or forwarded (I've tried setting it for port 7 and when that didn't work changed the rule to use port 9. UDP is also what I've set it for not TCP) At this point I'm not sure if I'm understanding how the Wake on WAN and Wake on LAN packets work.  So if someone can help me it would be appreciated. I know Remote Desktop Management feature can be used with Port Triggering, but waking devices seems to be alluding me.

If anyone can help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is supposed to *trigger* your rules?

'Port Triggering' is named that way because it lets you create dynamic rules where some specific activity – some type of **outgoing** traffic – causes the router to add a temporary rule for incoming traffic. (For example, when your computer connects to IRC server X:6697, *that* activates a rule forwarding port 113 to the same computer.) Take a look at, for example, how [Netgear](https://kb.netgear.com/24295/What-is-port-triggering-and-how-does-it-work-with-my-Nighthawk-router) describes it:

> *With port triggering, the router monitors traffic to the Internet from an outbound "trigger" port that you specify. For outbound traffic from that port, the router saves the IP address of the computer that sent the traffic. The router temporarily opens the incoming port or ports that you specify in your rule, and forwards that incoming traffic to that destination.*

That's how it is able to "share" the same port number between hosts, too. It's not actually sharing the whole port all the time, it just keeps re-assigning it to whichever host "requested" it last (and possibly for a limited time).

But no such thing happens when you're trying to send a wake packet from the outside. There is no corresponding outbound traffic that would activate the port-triggering rule (after all the computer is asleep and cannot produce any packets of its own), so the rule will never activate.

So if you want Wake-on-LAN or indeed any other service to work purely based on inbound requests, port-triggering is the completely wrong tool to use. You *want* the static port forwarding rule to be always active.

> however port forwarding is very insecure as the specified ports are always open.

It's not really. There is nothing insecure about ports themselves, it's all about the *services* which are listening for packets on those ports. If your computer isn't running any service expecting traffic on port 9, then it's as good as closed.

The packets have no ability to start bothering another service on different port or even on a completely different host if that happens – if they were sent to port 9 on host A, they will go to port 9 on host A and nowhere else.

(And besides, if your *incoming* packets sent from the outside were able to activate the port-triggering rule, then anyone else's packets could do the same – it would be no different from always having the port open!)

Comment: Then what would be the solution to have say ports 7 or 9 be forwarded for multiple devices at once? So from the Xfinity xfi modems do not allow port 9 to be open for all devices on the network. The admin advanced ui tool in the modem used to have an option for undesignated devices for port forwarding or I could open port 9 on as many devices as I want simultaneously. But with the upgrade to xfi that feature is locked out and gone. Using xfi settings limits me to a single forwarded port for a single device. Is the more a work around?

Comment: For WoL it doesn't need to _be_ port 9 or any other specific port. (The Ethernet card just looks for the special data, it doesn't care about the protocol.) So if your WoL client allows specifying a custom port (most do), then feel free to use UDP port 9 for one machine, port 10 for another, port 11 or even 9001 for the third, etc. Just try to avoid those ports which have a real UDP-based service running on the system (this is the only reason why most apps use port 9 specifically).